# React Native TypeScript Error: Module '"react-native"' has no exported member 'Appearance'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've recently implemented dark mode into my app, but having an issue with an error when building the npm package with `npm build`. The code works, but is there a way or a reason to remove this error?

[React Native Docs: Appearance](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance)

**Error**

```
src/ContactActionSheet.tsx:3:10 - error TS2305: Module '"react-native"' has no exported member 'Appearance'.

3 import { Appearance, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View, Linking, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

**JSX**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { Appearance, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View, Linking, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

// Dark Mode
const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue was with the npm package `@types/react-native` needing to be updated.

Comment: `npm install --save @types/react-native`

Answer (score 2):

I tried `npm install --save @types/react-native` but it didn't work. I had to add `@latest` at the end on order to get a proper update of the version. try this command `npm install --save @types/react-native@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for following up with a response. After checking what version I was on, I discovered I didn't even have the `@types/react-native` module added. Once I added that, my issue was resolved. Strange how if you start a project with TypeScript, it is not guaranteed to even have that dependency.

Comment: It just depends on the package. Some NPM packages have the types built in, but other NPM packages have separate `@types/` packages

Comment: Here are some examples of separate types packages: `@testing-library/jest-dom`, `@types/jest`, `@types/react-redux`, `@types/react-router-dom`, `@types/redux-logger`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vscode and find this error message linting, it is because you didn't add `@types/...` including `@types/react-native`

Comment: Edit: I solved by launching a terminal and running npm install --save @types/react-native

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error but solved it by launching a terminal and running:

```
npm install --save@types/react-native
```