# Module '\"react-native\"' has no exported member 'StyleSheet'

Tags: typescript, react-native

This problem is the same as one posted on [SO 2 and a half years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334338/react-native-typescript-error-module-react-native-has-no-exported-member-a).

I'm running React Native and it recognises basic react native elements within js files, but it doesn't recognise these same elements in tsx files. The link posted above suggests installing the latest version of [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) Which I have done, but I'm still getting the same error. I've tried reloading the developer window and I thought I had fixed it, but these errors have come back again.

Here is the error in full

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/file.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2305",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Module '\"react-native\"' has no exported member 'StyleSheet'.",
    "source": "ts",
}]
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Not sure what to do here, all help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried installing ```@types/react-native```?

Comment: You were right! I've just been following the docs on how to convert a react native app to typescript. After adding the libraries the errors went. I have nice new ones now. Umm. Errors